# Creating objects and adding properties and methods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I have just started to study objects in javaScript and have run into some troubles. I will explain step by step what I have tried to do and will ask my questions when there is a step I don´t fully grasp.

I created an object called person. Then I wanted to add a property named "firstName" with the value "Isaac". To do this, I created a constructing function.

```
var person = new print1("Isaac")

function print1(firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
```

So far no problems. However, I want to make the function return "My name is " + person.firstName + "." but I cannot make it when I put it inside there.

```
function print1(firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    return "My name is " + this.firstName + "." 
}
```

My idea is that I should be able to just call person.print1() and "My name is Isaac." would appear.

Why does it not work? Or can´t I even do like this?

I have tried similar thing with the function below but Can´t make it work with that either. When I run it I get an error message saying "person.print2() is not a function.

```
function print2(firstName, lastName, nationality) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.nationality = nationality;
    return "My name is " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + " from " + this.nationality + ".";
}
console.log(person.print2());

person = new print2("Isaac", "Newton", "England");
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Look for JavaScript Object Creation Patterns on Google, e.g. http://leoasis.github.io/posts/2013/01/24/javascript-object-creation-patterns.

Comment: Suggest you learn some JavaScript fundamentals.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem is that you're trying to conflate a *constructor function* and a *method* into one thing. They're distinct things you define distinctly.

So you'd have a constructor function (the convention is for them to have an upper-case first letter):

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

...and then you can add a method to the objects created using that constructor function by adding them to the function's `prototype` object:

```
Person.prototype.print1 = function() {
    return "My name is " + this.name;
};
```

When you call

```
var person = new Person("Isaac");
```

...the `new` operator creates a new object and gives it an underlying *prototype* which comes from the `Person.prototype` property, then calls the `Person` function with `this` referring to that new object, and our code in `Person` stores the name that was passed in on the object as the `name` property.

When you call `print1` on that, `this` is again set to refer to the object, and so `this.name` gives us the name:

```
console.log(person.print1()); // "My name is Isaac"
```

Live example of all that:

```js
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.print1 = function() {
  return "My name is " + this.name;
};

var person = new Person("Isaac");

snippet.log(person.print1()); // "My name is Isaac"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

You don't *have* to define methods on the `Person.prototype` object, you can also define them within the constructor function, like this:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.print1 = function() {
        return "My name is " + this.name;
    };
}
```

The advantage to using the prototype is that all of the objects created via `new Person` share the same underlying prototype, and so they share the methods, which is useful for memory-efficiency; when you define the method within the constructor function, they aren't shared (although modern JavaScript engines can optimize that). There are times when it's useful to define them in constructors, for instance when you want them to have access to information you don't make available on the object itself (e.g., truly private — completey encapsulated — information).

Using the prototype also means that as they all share the same methods, if necessary you can *redefine* those methods, and all existing instances immediately start using the redefined vesions, like so:

```js
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.print1 = function() {
  return "My name is " + this.name;
};

var isaac = new Person("Isaac");
var joe = new Person("Joe");

snippet.log(isaac.print1()); // "My name is Isaac"
snippet.log(joe.print1());   // "My name is Joe"

Person.prototype.print1 = function() {
  return "Hi there, my name is " + this.name;
};

snippet.log(isaac.print1()); // "Hi there, my name is Isaac"
snippet.log(joe.print1());   // "Hi there, my name is Joe"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

Any good JavaScript book can walk you through this stuff, here's an off-the-cuff list:

- *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide* by David Flanagan
- *Eloquent JavaScript* by Marijn Haverbeke (which is available online for free)

You'll also have people recommending *JavaScript: The Good Parts* by Douglas Crockford. I don't recommend it for people just starting out, it's more for people who already know the language well, and is primarily an opinion piece describing what Crockford did and didn't like about JavaScript back when it was written (both JavaScript and Crockford's opinions have moved on since then). Crockford is intelligent and well-informed, but unfortunately, in my view, he doesn't do a good job of separating his opinions from facts, making parts of the book a bit misleading, particularly to beginners.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `person.print1` because there is no `print1` method in your object. Returning the value from the constructor doesn't work, as it's already returning the object that you create.

To call a method on the object, you need to add a method to the object. You can add a method as a property in the constructor:

```js
    function Person(firstName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.print = function() {
        return "My name is " + this.firstName + ".";
      };
    }

    var isaac = new Person("Isaac");
    // output result in Stackoverflow snippet
    document.write(isaac.print());
```

You can also put methods in the prototype of the class:

```js
function Person(firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
}

Person.prototype = {
  print: function() {
    return "My name is " + this.firstName + ".";
  }
};

var isaac = new Person("Isaac");
// output result in Stackoverflow snippet
document.write(isaac.print());
```

You can even extend an object by adding methods to it after creation:

```js
function Person(firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
}

var isaac = new Person("Isaac");
var john = new Person("John");

isaac.print = function() {
  return "My name is " + this.firstName + ".";
};

john.print = function() {
  return "Call me " + this.firstName + ".";
};

// output result in Stackoverflow snippet
document.write(isaac.print());
document.write(john.print());
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, constructors should start with capital letter:

```
var person = new Person("Isaac");

function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
};
```

Secondly, define a `print` method like this:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.print = function() {
        return "My name is " + this.name;
    };
};
```

and invoke it calling `person.print()`. Note that in this case you need to define `Person` constructor before instantiating `person`.

There is much more you need to go through at the beginning (e.g. prototyping). Also, check this amazing article on JavaScript Object Creation Patterns: http://leoasis.github.io/posts/2013/01/24/javascript-object-creation-patterns.